# Putting XML values into a selection

Tags: php, html, xml

I have this XML returned by a server:

```
<cs><c n="flightsearch"><q n="XSD" v="<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">  <xsd:element name="rows"> <xsd:complexType> <xsd:sequence> <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="row"> <xsd:complexType> <xsd:sequence>  <xsd:element name="FlightID" type="xsd:string" />  <xsd:element name="FlightType" type="xsd:string" />  <xsd:element name="FlightDate" type="xsd:string" />  <xsd:element name="FlightTime" type="xsd:string" />  <xsd:element name="fromairport" type="xsd:string" />  <xsd:element name="toairport" type="xsd:string" />  <xsd:element name="Route" type="xsd:string" />  <xsd:element name="seats" type="xsd:string" />  <xsd:element name="Price" type="xsd:string" />  <xsd:element name="ChildPrice" type="xsd:string" />  <xsd:element name="Duration" type="xsd:string" />  <xsd:element name="flightsummary" type="xsd:string" />  <xsd:element name="flightimage" type="xsd:string" /> </xsd:sequence> <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:int" /> </xsd:complexType> </xsd:element> </xsd:sequence> </xsd:complexType> </xsd:element> </xsd:schema>"/><q n="XML" v="<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <rows xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation = "Articles_Schema.xsd" >  <row id="1">   <FlightID><![CDATA[FLT49596|ART02504.20170715||CREEKSILVER]]></FlightID>   <FlightType><![CDATA[Seawings Creek Silver]]></FlightType>   <FlightDate>7/15/2017</FlightDate>   <FlightTime><![CDATA[10:45]]></FlightTime>   <fromairport><![CDATA[Dubai Creek Golf]]></fromairport>   <toairport><![CDATA[Dubai Creek Golf]]></toairport>   <Route><![CDATA[DCG/DCG]]></Route>   <seats>9</seats>   <Price><![CDATA[AED 1,695.00 per person]]></Price>   <ChildPrice><![CDATA[AED 1,440.00 per child]]></ChildPrice>   <Duration>40</Duration>   <flightsummary><![CDATA[Named to commemorate Dubais historic pearling heritage, this tour starts as you gently exit the harbour where you marvel at Dubais breath-taking collection of sights. After passing the outstanding Dubai Marina you are treated to a birds eye view of the world-famous The Palm JumeirahTM, then onto the seven star Burj Al Arab hotel, before moving inland to Downtown Dubai and past the Burj Dubai, destined to be the worlds tallest building, followed by a sweeping arc out to The World islands, before heading back along the coastline for a second pass and a gentle splash back down to earth.]]></flightsummary>   <flightimage><![CDATA[]]></flightimage> </row> <row id="2">   <FlightID><![CDATA[FLT49598|ART02506.20170715||CREEKSILVER]]></FlightID>   <FlightType><![CDATA[Seawings Creek Silver]]></FlightType>   <FlightDate>7/15/2017</FlightDate>   <FlightTime><![CDATA[11:00]]></FlightTime>   <fromairport><![CDATA[Dubai Creek Golf]]></fromairport>   <toairport><![CDATA[Dubai Creek Golf]]></toairport>   <Route><![CDATA[DCG/DCG]]></Route>   <seats>9</seats>   <Price><![CDATA[AED 1,695.00 per person]]></Price>   <ChildPrice><![CDATA[AED 1,440.00 per child]]></ChildPrice>   <Duration>40</Duration>   <flightsummary><![CDATA[Named to commemorate Dubais historic pearling heritage, this tour starts as you gently exit the harbour where you marvel at Dubais breath-taking collection of sights. After passing the outstanding Dubai Marina you are treated to a birds eye view of the world-famous The Palm JumeirahTM, then onto the seven star Burj Al Arab hotel, before moving inland to Downtown Dubai and past the Burj Dubai, destined to be the worlds tallest building, followed by a sweeping arc out to The World islands, before heading back along the coastline for a second pass and a gentle splash back down to earth.]]></flightsummary>   <flightimage><![CDATA[]]></flightimage> </row> </rows> "/></c></cs>
```

How do I put it into a radio button in PHP like this:

- Seawings Creek Silver
  Date: 7/15/2017
  Flight Time: 10:45
  Route: DCG/DCG
- Seawings Creek Silver
  Date: 7/15/2017
  Flight Time: 11:00
  Route: DCG/DCG

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: That XML isn't even valid - The values in the attributes aren't escaped.